# Solving exponential equation using sympy?

Tags: sympy

I want to solve following simple equation using sympy

```
2^(x-y)=1
```

where x and y are +ve integers

my expected result is

```
x=y
```

When I try to solve using sympy

```
x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
solve(2**(x-y)-1, x)
```

I  am getting following result

```
[log(2**y)/log(2)]
```

What extra steps I have to following to get expected results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since logarithm and exponents are tricky for complex numbers, the variables should be declared real. In complex numbers, 2^(x-y)=1 does *not* imply that x=y.

```
from sympy import *
x,y = symbols('x,y', real=True)
solve(2**(x-y)-1, x)[0]
```

Result: `y`

(Related function: [`expand_log`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/simplification.html#expand-log), though it's not needed in this example.)